# How to handle not finding OpenCV in source code

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake, c-preprocessor

I have built a C++ library that depends on OpenCV. However, sometimes I don't need to use OpenCV, and I compile the code without it.

The idea is, when the `OpenCV_Found` variable in CMake is true, there would be a pre-processor variable similar to the `OpenCV_Found` variable, but in the C++ code. In other words, I want to do something like this:

```
#ifdef OpenCV_Found
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#endif
```

My question is:

Does OpenCV provide a similar variable like that? Or do I have to define it manually, and send it to the target compilation flags?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use CMake to *forward* the `OpenCV_Found` CMake definition to your C++ source code. You can use a [generator expression](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html#boolean-generator-expressions) in [`target_compile_definitions()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_compile_definitions.html) like this:

```
add_executable(MyExe ${MY_SOURCES})
target_compile_definitions(MyExe PUBLIC $<$<BOOL:${OpenCV_Found}>:OpenCV_Found>)
```

This will add `OpenCV_Found` as a pre-processor definition to the `MyExe` target when the `${OpenCV_Found}` CMake variable evaluates to True. When the CMake variable `${OpenCV_Found}` evaluates to False (case-insensitive equal of `0`, `FALSE`, `OFF`, `N`, `NO`, `IGNORE`, or `NOTFOUND`), the `OpenCV_Found` pre-processor definition is omitted.